# How to trace ActionScript inside web page?

Tags: flash, debugging, actionscript

I have Firefox, Firebug, Flashbug and *.fla + *.as files of flash widged. Is it possible to debug it with tracing trough as code with variable watch etc? How to?

**EDIT**

I HAVE flasbug and can see trace command output. But I need to do step by step debugging as other debuggers do, and also as Flash Professional can do with standalone flash movies.

Comment: try to use flashbug https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/flashbug/

Comment: a while back I wrote some code that hooked into `ExternalInterface` to make use of `console.log` and the like so that I didn't have to install a separate addon just for flash. You'd also need to set the `allowscriptaccess` parameter when you embed the flash. As a warning, it involved calling `eval` to initialize a function so that I had hooks to `console.log`.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use the Flash debugger. :) See [this article from Adobe](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/UsingFlash/help.html?content=WSE9184681-3417-4849-B487-8D6C2F8CC688.html).

Or use the [MonsterDebugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/).

Comment: Thanks! I saw this article, but didn't understand it. The phrases like "remote debugging is limited to files located on the same localhost" do unsettle me. What "remote" word can mean if it is the same localhost? Also here: "if you upload the file to a remote server you will not be able to step through code". I need namely this: trace file from remote server.

Comment: 1) It means you can't debug things in the debugger, unless you're running the server on your own machine. 2) You can use traces anywhere, and you don't need the debugger. All you need to do is use the content debugger Flash Player and enable logging. See this post:http://jpauclair.net/2010/02/10/mmcfg-treasure

Comment: Or: Use the MonsterDebugger ;)

Comment: With monster debugger will I be able to debug flash applets embedded into web pages shown from remote server (not my own machine)?

Answer (score 0):

I was messing around with `ExternalInterface` because I thought there might be a better way to access the console than my previous method, and I discovered that the first parameter of `ExternalInterface.call` could specify more than just a function to call.

I wrote this function to simplify using the JavaScript `console` and `trace` down to:

```
Console.log(...);
```

Or in a conditional compilation block:

```
CONFIG::DEBUG {
    Console.log(...);
}
```

---

```
/**
 * @author    zzzzBov <zzzzbov@gmail.com>
 * @version   0.1
 * @since     2012-02-24
 */
package com.zzzzbov.debug {
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

    /**
     * `com.zzzzbov.debug.Console` is a debugging tool to interface with web browsers' developer consoles.
     */
    public class Console {

        /**
         * The hidden utility method to make `ExternalInterface` calls to JavaScript.
         * 
         * @param type the type of console function that will be called
         * @param args the array of arguments to pass to the console[type] function
         */
        private static function console(type:String, args:Array = null):void {
            //prevents an additional `null` from being passed as an argument when the second parameter is skipped
            if (args === null) {
                args = [];
            }
            //Checks that the ExternalInterface is available and that console[type] exists
            if (ExternalInterface.available && ExternalInterface.call('function () {return !!(console && ("' + type + '" in console));}')) {
                //calls the console[type] function with the provided arguments.
                ExternalInterface.call.apply(ExternalInterface, ['console.'+type].concat(args));
            } else {
                //calls `trace` if console[type] isn't available
                trace.apply(null, [type].concat(args));
            }
        }

        /**
         * Checks the truthiness of {@param expr}; if the assertion fails, it also prints out {@param args}.
         * 
         * @param expr an expression to test
         * @param args the message to print to the console
         */
        public static function assert(expr:*, ... args):void {
            console('assert', [expr].concat(args));
        }

        /**
         * Clears the console of messages
         */
        public static function clear():void {
            console('clear');
        }

        /**
         * Writes the number of times that count was executed. The {@param title} will be printed in addition to the count.
         * 
         * Warning: No IE support
         * 
         * @param title A title for a particular counter
         */
        public static function count(title:String = null):void {
            console('count', title != null ? [title] : []);
        }

        /**
         * Writes the arguments to the console.
         * 
         * Warning: No IE support.
         * 
         * @param args the arguments to print in the console
         */
        public static function debug(... args):void {
            console('debug', args);
        }

        /**
         * Prints an interactive listing of all properties on {@param obj}.
         * 
         * @param obj the object to expand
         */
        public static function dir(obj:*):void {
            console('dir', [obj]);
        }

        /**
         * Prints an XML source tree of an HTML or XML element.
         * 
         * Warning: No IE support; source tree may not be fully supported.
         */
        public static function dirxml(node:*):void {
            console('dirxml', [node]);
        }

        /**
         * Writes the arguments to the console as an error message.
         * 
         * @param args the arguments to print in the console
         */
        public static function error(... args):void {
            console('error', args);
        }
        /**
         * Writes a message to the console and opens a nested block for future console messages.
         * 
         * Warning: No IE support. Call {@link #groupEnd()} to close the block.
         * 
         * @param args the arguments to print in the console
         */
        public static function group(... args):void {
            console('group', args);
        }

        /**
         * Writes a message to the console and opens a collapsed, nested block for future console messages.
         * 
         * Warning: No IE support. Call {@link #groupEnd()} to close the block.
         * 
         * @param args the arguments to print in the console
         */
        public static function groupCollapsed(... args):void {
            console('groupCollapsed', args);
        }

        /**
         * Closes the block most recently opened by {@link #group(...)} or {@link #groupCollapsed(...)}.
         * 
         * Warning: No IE support.
         */
        public static function groupEnd():void {
            console('groupEnd');
        }

        /**
         * Writes the arguments to the console as an informational message.
         * 
         * @param args the arguments to print in the console
         */
        public static function info(... args):void {
            console('info', args);
        }

        /**
         * Writes the arguments to the console.
         * 
         * The first argument may use a printf-like syntax for substituting subsequent arguments into a formatted message.
         * 
         * @param args the arguments to print in the console
         */
        public static function log(... args):void {
            console('log', args);
        }

        /**
         * Turns on the JavaScript profiler.
         * 
         * Call {@link #profileEnd()} to stop profiling and print the profiler report.
         * 
         * @param title the title to print in the header of the profile report
         */
        public static function profile(title:String = null):void {
            console('profile', title != null ? [title] : []);
        }

        /**
         * Turns off the JavaScript profiler and prints the profiler report.
         */
        public static function profileEnd():void {
            console('profileEnd');
        }
        /**
         * Creates a new timer with the given name.
         * 
         * Warning: No IE support. Call {@link #timeEnd(name)} to stop the timer and print the elapsed time.
         * 
         * @param name the name of the timer to start
         */
        public static function time(name:String):void {
            console('time', [name]);
        }

        /**
         * Stops the timer with the provided name and prints the elapsed time to the console.
         * 
         * Warning: No IE support. Call {@link #time(name)} to start a timer of a given name.
         * 
         * @param name the name of the timer to stop
         */
        public static function timeEnd(name:String):void {
            console('timeEnd', [name]);
        }

        /**
         * Writes the arguments to the console as a warning.
         * 
         * @param args the arguments to print in the console
         */
        public static function warn(... args):void {
            console('warn', args);
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>Let me know if you spot any issues, or have any suggestions.</sub>